# How rotate camera to Mouse click

Tags: unity-game-engine, mouse

I make viewer of models (with Unity3d). Now I make mouse interaction with model. How rotate camera to mouse click position. http://prntscr.com/990q9y

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand what you want. You have like a fixed point model, and you want to check the mouse position and change the model rotation based on the click (not on the drag)? You can try change localEulerAngles after making some assumptions based on screen position: Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

Comment: Maybe this post can be helpfull : [Camera Rotate Around Object With Mouse Drag](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/218119/camera-rotate-around-object-with-mouse-drag-help.html)

Comment: No, I need rotate camera to position mouse click. http://prntscr.com/990v9p. I want change rotation of camera, but not of model.

Comment: oh, ok. I answered wrong. I will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

You want "click", right? 
Oh, You want to change camera.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
             RaycastHit hit;
             Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                 if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                 {
                   Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles=hit.point;
                 } 
         }

//or try to fix the z thing:
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
             {
                 Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                 Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles = ray.origin + (ray.direction * 4.5f);
             }
```

I see this here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/376735/get-world-coordinates-from-mouse-click.html

and maybe this can help you a lot: [How to constrain rotation from mouse input in unity 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792490/how-to-constrain-rotation-from-mouse-input-in-unity-5?rq=1)

Comment: But this move object to Mouse Click (or touch) :(. I need rotate camera to mouse click position http://prntscr.com/990v9p

Comment: I've edited, pls see if this make sense for you and if works as you need

Comment: I believe you need a lil edits to find a exact value of rotation instead of the exact click point. I believe the click point will be a 2D value on screen? I need to get out real quick, I will edit this soon I can focus sit and think again. Real quick.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I too think that neet calculation of rotation based on click point. But I am stuck.

Comment: Ok so. Since the z position will be confusing, I put a fixed distance for test as 4.5f. Check this new edited answer and if have some sense for you.

Comment: Thinking here: I want to clarify: thinking as a "camera man". You want the camera man to stay at his position and just turn the camera TO the point clicked "2D" or to the camera man to be positioned on the point clicked and rotate to keep still looking at the model?

Answer (score 0):

This code work, but how smoothly rotate?

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
RaycastHit hit;
var pos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10);
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
transform.transform.LookAt(hit.point);
player.UpdatePosition();
}
}
```

Comment: you can add fragments of the total value that would fulfil. you cache the mouse position. and check if the camera position is > or <. and you add or subtract the fraction until is reaches the desired position. lets say, mouse.x is 3 and camera.x is 0. you cache the value 3. and make it add +0.2f until "(int)camera.x" it reaches "(int)cached.x" (that is 3).